# IF result is IN ('m','f') THEN PRINT (tsql)

Tags: sql, t-sql, if-statement, case

There is a 'gender' field in Member table that has either 'm' or 'f' as values. I want to PRINT 'PASS' if both 'm' and 'f' exist in the field and PRINT 'FAIL' if:

1. only one of two values(m or f) exists

or 2. value other than m or f exists

or 3. null record exists.

When I run the following code, I get "Subquery returned more than 1 value" message.

```
IF ((SELECT DISTINCT Gender FROM dbo.Member) in ('M','F'))
PRINT 'PASS'
ELSE
PRINT 'FAIL'`
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT sum(case when gender= 'M' then 1 else 0 end) M,  
                sum(case when gender= 'F' then 1 else 0 end) F,
                sum(case when gender not in('F', 'M') then 1 else 0 end ) Other  
         FROM dbo.Member) a
      WHERE a.M>0 and a.F>0 and a.Other=0)     
PRINT 'PASS'
ELSE
PRINT 'FAIL'
```